# Strange characters in TIME$ in QB in DOSbox (Linux vs. dos)

Tags: qb64

I have been using VBdos (QB dialect) in DOSbox and have found the Time$
is no longer maxed out at 23:59:59 but instead returns hours as

99:59:59

which I cannot parse. I am fudging it instead with S$=Format$(Now,"hh:mm:ss")

In fact, after leaving machine online for 4 days w/o suspend/sleep the date$
returns boot date and dos returns current date: that is 09-02-2019 in linux
as opposed to today: 09-05-2019 which is not a problem. So, anyway, my question is that linux time$ is returned as hh:mm:ss where sometimes the
hours are ;8:00:00 and sometimes >8:00:00 and sometimes =8:00:00 and
I would like to know why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is in C:\Dosbox-x\Dosbox-X.conf where

```
synchronize time = true
```

sets the clock to the current host. And traps midnight clock roll-over.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a bug in the BASIC interpreter you're using.

The ASCII characters which follow `9` are `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, and `@`, followed by the uppercase letters. My suspicion is that the interpreter is using these characters as if they were digits higher than 9 -- `;8` is probably meant to be 118, for instance.